# Ridge Extrusion Pattern Modeling

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender.I've been trying to find a tut to teach me how to make such pattern (background, behind bottle). Does anyone nows how I can make that?
Thanks in adance[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create this shape:

[image]

Give it an *Array* modifier:

[image]

At last give it a *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode, 360° on Z):

[image]